# Symfony 2: Import excel file in the dabase (PHPExcel)

Tags: php, symfony

I need to upload an excel file and import the content in the database to the related table.

I have already created a script to import it. The script below works properly

```
 $excelObj = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject($path_file);
 $sheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

 //READ EXCEL FILE CONTENT
 foreach($sheet as $i=>$row) {
 if($i !== 1) {
$account = $em->getRepository('ExcelBundle:Users')->findOneByUsername($row['A']);
                    if(!$account) {
                        $user = new Users();
                    }

                    $user->setName($row['A']); 
                    $user->setUsername($row['B']);
                    $user->setEmail($row['C']);
                    //... and so on


                    $em->persist($user);
                    $em->flush();
  }
  }
```

Now, instead of importing the row A, row B...etc of the excel file I need to import the name of the row.
**name username email** ...and so on

```
 $user->setName($row['name']); 
 $user->setUsername($row['username']);
 $user->setEmail($row['email']);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to map the headings row (row #1) to the actual values in each subsequent row

```
foreach($sheet as $i=>$row) {
    if($i == 1) {
        $headings = $row;
    } else {
        $row = array_combine($headings, $row);
        .... do the rest of your stuff here

        $user->setName($row['name']); 
        $user->setUsername($row['username']);
        $user->setEmail($row['email']);

        ....
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. As I rarely worked with PHPExcel I did not quite understand your suggestion. ...do the rest of your stuff here

Comment: the code I've shown is the mapping code to create `$row['name']`, `$row['username']`, `$row['email']`,etc

Comment: `do the rest of your stuff here` means do the work that your code is already doing: `$account = $em->getRepository('ExcelBundle:Users')->findOneByUsername($row['name']); if(!$account) { $user = new Users(); } $user->setName($row['name']); $user->setUsername($row['username']); $user->setEmail($row['email']); //... and so on $em->persist($user); $em->flush();`  etc....

Comment: Thanks for the explanations